# Implementing counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, timer

I have designed counter as follows.

I got the timer seconds from the server. And converted to hours, minutes, seconds.

```
   timerInterval = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        if(hours.toString().length == 1){hours = "0"+hours;}
        if(minutes.toString().length == 1){minutes = "0"+minutes;}
        if(seconds.toString().length == 1){seconds = "0"+seconds;}

       if(seconds > 0){
            seconds--;
            if(seconds.toString().length == 1){seconds = "0"+seconds;}
        }
        else if(seconds == 0 && (minutes > 0)){
            minutes = minutes - 1;
            seconds = 59;
        }
        else if(minutes == 0 && (hours > 0)){
           hours = hours - 1; 
           minutes = 59;
        }

        if(hours == 0 && minutes ==0 && seconds ==0){
            clearInterval(timerInterval);
            localStorage.removeItem("endTime");
            $(".submitTest").click();
        }

        $("#timer").html(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        localStorage['endTime'] = (hours*3600+minutes*60+seconds);
    },1000);
```

It displays the timer.

**Problem with this**

User can edit the timer and cheat.

**Solutions I found**

1) Store the timer last time in the server side. When user submits, we can calculate submission time against the time stored in the server.

```
**Problem**: If I send submission time, user can edit it. So no use of storing 
         it in the server.
```

2) I can just send the data to the server when timer expires or user submits. 
And I check the current time against the store time in the server.

**Problem**: Stored time in the server: 10:25PM.
          Server sends data to the client with duration of 25minutes at the time of 10:00pm.

There must be a delay in the data reaches the client. For example, it reaches 10:00 05seconds. And user submits exactly after 25 minutes [means timer expires]. And there must be a delay in the data which reaches the server. So it reaches at 10:25 20s[05+15seconds delay]. I stored the end time in the server as 10:25pm. So 20 seconds delay would fail as user cheated.

Solution is to have a +/- time. For example I would allow 10:27pm as valid time[2min extra]

But How does this 2min would be a valid one?

3) **Server Sent Events**
     I faced the same issue as second one. 
     But here solution is different: If timer expires on the server side, collect data from the user without waiting for his submission and do the submission action on the server side. But still user can stop JS which sends data to the server.

How do I solve this timer issues? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sidenote: you tagged as php, so where does that come into play?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I store timer in the php session. So I tagged it

Comment: what kind of html element is `#timer`?

Comment: @mjr It is a div to show the timer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store in session when the user require the page and also send to the page the time stored in session and keep the timer running in the front-end. When user do the submit you check on server-side the time stored in session and the time submitted, of course there will be a little difference of seconds or milliseconds. So you can define a margin to consider as a fraud.